# Access Jt400 userindex

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, jt400

when trying to access userindex I have an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.ibm.as400.access.UserIndexNativeImplILE.nativeOpen([B)I
    at com.ibm.as400.access.UserIndexNativeImplILE.nativeOpen(Native Method)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.UserIndexNativeImplILE.open(UserIndexNativeImplILE.java:51)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.UserIndex.open(UserIndex.java:429)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.UserIndex.findEntries(UserIndex.java:318)


AS400 system = new AS400(IP,USER,PASS);                               
UserIndex ui = new UserIndex(system, "/QSYS.LIB/LIB.LIB/USERINDEX.USRIDX");
ui.setMustUseNativeMethods(true);
ui.findEntries("MYKEY",ui.FIND_BETWEEN,1);
```

Any idea ?

Update:
Webservice is running on a différent machine. Other commands like commandcall are working. If i comment out native methods, same exception

Comment: It appears that you are running the java code on IBM i ... do you have the JAVA_HOME environment variable set?  Is the system current on the Java group PTF's?

Comment: What happens if you comment out the line telling it that it must use native methods?  `UnsatisfiedLinkError` usually means that a native library is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are **not** running the code on an iSeries server. Correct? It will only work when running *directly* on an iSeries server.